# What are some methods for indexing and searching content from multiple sites?

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing, elastic

Pretend you have a small client that is on `Sitecore 8.2` on-premise (virtual servers). Traffic is pretty light, and they get away with using just 2 servers (1 DB and 1 Web). Needless to say budget is limited here and factors into all their decisions. They have their main website on Sitecore, and host some landing pages, and whitepapers on `HubSpot`. They would like to implement a search that lives on their `Sitecore` site, but searches both `Sitecore` and `HubSpot` content (and documents would be a bonus).

Unfortunately, aside from the free version, `Coveo` is not in the budget.

My instinct is to:

1. Get the client to get another server or beef up an existing.
2. Install `Solr` or `Elastic Search` on one of the servers
3. Create a scheduled task that either uses Sitecore's indexing pipeline, or an external site crawler to spider the page output (like Google) daily.

But I think this would be a fun topic to get some community input on, that would also feedback into other people pondering something similar.

Comment: "Feedback" as such isn't really appropriate here - you need to go to Community or Slack for that.

Comment: This surprises me. Considering that Slack content is short lived, and this could be a valuable discussion to the community I'm surprised. Wouldn't this type of content make Sitecore stack exchange more valuable and have more searchable traffic? No sweat though, communities do disagree.

Comment: Have to say, I felt this is a good question for the community and one that I've come across a few times (indexing Sitecore + external content).

Comment: I think the question is a good one. But the wording makes it a bad fit for SSE. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion. So reword to get a specific answer and we can reopen.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a valuable discussion. It is. But it is exactly that - a discussion. This is a Q&A database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have good idea. 
We did something similar to our previous client where they had documents stored in their internal system. Documents where indexed by another Solr server. Then during night indexes were moved to Sitecore Solr server and replaced old document index. We had a custom Solr core for these documents and used it in document search on Sitecore.
Indexes were moved via Powershell scripts.

Comment: Thanks Chorpo, I didn't even consider multiple indexes and powershell. I was thinking just a sequential build of a single index, and probably some index switching to avoid any lapse in indexed content.